# change the way that the view with the controllers in ExoPlayer appears

Tags: exoplayer

I'm using exoplayer in my android app, and while the video is playing and I tap the screen, the display with the controllers does not appear smoothly, and I want to make it look smoothly, like a fade.. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2277#issuecomment-349538675 you can simply add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to your ExoPlayerView to have default fade in/out animation for your controller